# Getting "Failed to create lock" exception when performing parallel writes using RocksDB in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, rocksdb

I am using below dependency for RocksDb.

**rocksdbjni » 3.5.1**

Below code I am calling from Multiple Threads.

```
public static void test(){
    try {
        RocksDB.loadLibrary();
        RocksDB rocksDB = RocksDB.open("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\db");
        if(rocksDB.get("abc".getBytes()) == null){
            rocksDB.put("abc".getBytes(),"cde".getBytes());
        }else{
            System.out.print(new String(rocksDB.get("abc".getBytes())));
        }
        rocksDB.close();
    } catch (RocksDBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When calling above parallely I am getting "**org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Failed to create lock file: C:\Users\Downloads\db/LOCK: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**" but when I am putting lock( or synchronized method ) on above code it's working fine.

I want to write in parallel in RocksDB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `RocksDB` object once and let your threads share it. It's not meant to be created for each thread (and can't share the same lock file).

Comment: Working now. I tried earlier same thing but didn't work.